# How to use username for logging in instead of email in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5.3

How can i set up a login system in Laravel 5.3 instead of email?

i tried to add in LoginController.php

> public function username(){
>           return 'username';
>       }

Answer (score 1):

So far You are doing everything right. To authenticate by other than `email` field You have to override `username()` method as You did. But I think You probably didn't changed login view. You have to change name of text field. I am talking about views/auth/login.blade.php and this chunk of code:

```
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('email', 'has-error') }}">
        {!! Form::label('email', trans('account/form.email'), ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {!! Form::text('email', old('email'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {!! $errors->first('email', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Replace every `email` with `username`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to be changed for your entire application go to "AuthenticatesUsers" trait, in "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php" then go to line "128", you should find this:

```
 /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
```

change it to:

```
 /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'name';
    }
```

Comment: Yo should never edit the vendor files, because in an update the files will overwritten